# Xamarin LongClick switch statement doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, button

i have a button on my UI, and when the user makes a long click, i want to use a switch statement, but it doesn't work.

```
bool test = true;

button.LongClick += Button_LongClick;

private void Button_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
{
        switch (test)
        {
            case true:
                // Toast error
                break;
            case false:
                // call a method
                break;
        }
}
```

I don't know why but the switch is not working, the method is always called, even if the bool is true.

Did i missed something?

Comment: `bool` is a type, do you have a `bool` *instance* that you are actually trying to use?

Comment: that shouldn't even compile - and why not use an `if` for a simple either or case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,`bool` is a type,we should define a variable of `bool`and assign a value to this variable.(eg. `true` or `false`).
For example ,you can use it like this:

```
 bool flag = true;

 button.LongClick += Button_LongClick;
 private void Button_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (flag)
    {
            case true:
                // Toast error
                Toast.MakeText(this,"the value of flag is true. " ,ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
            case false:
                // call a method
                Toast.MakeText(this, "the value of flag is false. ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
        }
    }
```